# Getting problems in Transaction Rollback in WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 with DSS 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

In my ESB 4.8.0, Dss is 3.1.0

I wish to insert the data reliably into database,for that i am getting one array list from client. That array i need to insert into 3 different tables.Each table gave to me returned generated key.which will help to insert into 2nd table,same process for 3rd table. for this i am using 3 different insertion operations in wso2esb using wso2dss,the insertion is happening nicely ..

**@My issue is while i am inserting into 2nd or 3rd table the error has been occurred due to network issue or any data related issue. In that case my transaction could be roll back.i have done in transaction mediator but it's helpful for within the sequence . it's not reflecting to any other sequence , so how could i do this.
Please help me solve this.**

```
My Array:-
{"uuid":"d5ec4a32-c75d-40e7-a28d-3bc363adea11","clientobservation":"client feedback","AuditeeName":"kmkale","auditorobservation":"Auditor feedback",
"QuestionsLists":{"QuestionsList":
[{"remark":"null","userid":0,"sectionQuestionMapId":423681068369563,"sectionId":377627438253095,"DataSize":0.0,"QuestionId":423547939522200,"pageId":0,"Rank":0.0,"auditid":1387444552915,"DataType":0,"answer":1,"IsAVPT":0,"chekBoxValue":0,"QuestionType":0,"IsFollowup":0,"LovType":0,"IsRemarks":0,"IsOptional":0},
{"remark":"null","userid":0,"sectionQuestionMapId":423681072203654,"sectionId":377627438777413,"DataSize":0.0,"QuestionId":423547939522435,"pageId":0,"Rank":0.0,"auditid":1387444552915,"DataType":0,"answer":1,"IsAVPT":0,"chekBoxValue":0,"QuestionType":0,"IsFollowup":0,"LovType":0,"IsRemarks":0,"IsOptional":0},
{"remark":"null","userid":0,"sectionQuestionMapId":423681072236423,"sectionId":377627438777413,"DataSize":0.0,"QuestionId":423547939522436,"pageId":0,"Rank":0.0,"auditid":1387444552915,"DataType":0,"answer":1,"IsAVPT":0,"chekBoxValue":0,"QuestionType":0,"IsFollowup":0,"LovType":0,"IsRemarks":0,"IsOptional":0},
{"remark":"null","userid":0,"sectionQuestionMapId":423681072269192,"sectionId":377627438777413,"DataSize":0.0,"QuestionId":423547939522437,"pageId":0,"Rank":0.0,"auditid":1387444552915,"DataType":0,"answer":0,"IsAVPT":0,"chekBoxValue":0,"QuestionType":0,"IsFollowup":0,"LovType":0,"IsRemarks":0,"IsOptional":0}
]},"DeviceId":"000000000000000","OUID":419978955163229,"longitude":0.0,"PartyBranchId":420523188651661,"PartyId":0,"ClientId":414474781000924,"TaskID":-1,"TemplateId":377557205353500,"Timestamp":1387444552915,"AuditorId":417823541659158,"AuditId":1387444552915,"latitude":0.0,"PScore":10,"syncStatus":0,"AScore":6}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For local transactions to work, you have to install DSS features in ESB and do the same thing instead of calling a remote DSS server. Because everything needs to be handled through a single thread and having DSS inside ESB is the only way to achieve this.

Comment: Where can i install the DSS features in ESB and how, will you explain me in detail

Comment: Refer to the Feature management documentation here:http://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Feature+Management.